# How to prove hypergeometric function inequality

Tags: inequality, hypergeometric-function

Looking for help on how to prove the following inequality:

$c\,(c-1-x)\,{}_2F_1(1,1\,;\hspace{1pt}c\,;x) \;\,\le\;\, (c-1)\,(c-x)\,{}_2F_1(1,1\,;\hspace{1pt}c+1\,;\,x), \;\;\; 0\le x<1,\; \, c>1 $

I have tried using Gauss contiguous relations, and linear transformation formulae from A&S and G&R. I have looked at the difference of the coefficients in the expansions.

Alternatively:

$$\frac{c\,(c-1-x)}{(c-1)\,(c-x)}\,{}_2F_1(1,1\,;\hspace{1pt}c\,;\,x)\;\;\le\;\; {}_2F_1(1,1\,;\hspace{1pt}c+1\,;x) \;\;\le\;\; {}_2F_1(1,1\,;\hspace{1pt}c\,;\,x),\\\quad\quad\quad\quad \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \;\; 0\le x<1,\;  c>1 $$

Also apparently true for $-1<c<1$. This arose in my research trying to prove convexity of the bias of $R^2$ in multiple linear regression.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: I have tried using Gauss contiguous relations, and linear transformation formulae from A&S and G&R. I have looked at the difference of the coefficients in the expansion. The first is positive and the rest are negative.

Comment: This arose in my research, not a class problem.

Comment: Don't tell me in the comments. Edit your post directly with what you have done.

Comment: Yes, I have plotted it for many values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Using the integral representation, the right side minus the left side of the first inequality above gives:

$\int_0^1 \frac{(1-t)^{c-2}((c+x)t+1)}{1-tx} dt$

which is positive for $0\le x<1$ and $c>-1$.

Comment: The integral representation is only valid for c>1 though according to A&S.

Comment: Can you give more details? Did you prove the inequality for $c>-1$ ("only valid for $c>1$")?

Comment: I used the integral representation for the hypergeometric function, which is in Abramowitz and Stegun 15.3.1, combined into the above integral. The integral representation is valid for c>1, so that step is not valid for -1<c<1 I guess. The integral seems to be valid for -1<c<1, and positive, but I'm not sure how the integral representation relates to the hypergeometric function in this case.

Comment: Actually just looking at the integral, you can pretty much see that it's infinite for $c\le 1$. So it is only valid for $c>1$.

Comment: The inequality does seem to be valid for for $c>-1$ though. Not sure how to prove that. Maybe a transformation of the hypergeometric functions and use of the integral representation.

Answer (score 0):

$$\, _2F_1(1,1;c;x)-\, _2F_1(1,1;c+1;x)=\Gamma (c)\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n \, \Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (c+n+1)}x^n$$

$$\frac{(c-1)\,(c-x)}{c\,(c-1-x)} \geq 1$$

Comment: Actually not so sure. Doesn't this just prove that:
$$ _2F_1(1,1;c;x) -\,_2F_1(1,1;c+1;x) \le \left(\frac{(c-1)(c-x)}{c(c-1-x)}-1 \right)\, _2F_1(1,1;c+1;x) $$

Comment: @japalmer. I worked the first difference only and this makes the first inequality. Now,  make a contour plot of  $\frac{(c-1)\,(c-x)}{c\,(c-1-x)} $

Comment: That is:
$$ 0 \le\, _2F_1(1,1;c;x) -\,_2F_1(1,1;c+1;x) \le \left(\frac{(c-1)(c-x)}{c(c-1-x)}-1 \right)\, _2F_1(1,1;c+1;x) $$

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. It seems to me you just showed that $_2F_1(1,1;c;x)\ge _2F_1(1,1;c+1;x)$.

Comment: Maybe you thought the last term in the alternative formulation was $c$ not $c+1$?

Comment: The first inequality in the alternative is known and just shown for reference. The point is to prove the second inequality, which doesn't follow from $(c-1)(c-1)/(c(c-1-x)) \ge 1$.